# Нужно ли отделять деепричастие запятой?

Tags: пунктуация, деепричастный-оборот

Предложение "Она покинула деревню(,) зная, что должна сделать".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В Вашем предложении нет ни одного наречия.

Деепричастный оборот отделяется запятой.

*Она покинула деревню, зная, что должна сделать.*